# What is the word for words that are 'two sides of the same coin'?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

What is the word for words that are 'two sides of the same coin' as they are not always opposites... such as heads and tails.

Complement?

An example would be ball and strike in baseball. They are the only two possibilities for a pitch not hit. Are the contexts?

Tragedy and comedy but not positive and negative.
Reading and writing and Peace and justice but not winning and losing.

Comment: I just read that your question can receive no more answers, so I guess the last 40 minutes I've spent on providing you with an answer have amounted to a waste of time. If, however, you'd like to read my answer, email me at the email address in my Stack Exchange bio. Don. P.S. I think it's a really decent answer!

Comment: @fev Let’s reopen this.

Comment: @Cascabel A poor decision to close.

Comment: @killing time You guys are getting thoughtlessly aggressive.

Comment: @Xanne I voted to close because the question (especially the last paragraph) lacked clarity - I still think it does.

Comment: Two sides of the same coin are always opposite sides. What doesn't change is the coin....

Comment: It's not clear if it's looking for a word to describe one of the options or both of the options together. There are lots of words for dividing into two (binary, dichotomy, etc), but does it mean that? Also, some of the examples aren't clear: notably "peace and justice": they're not interchangeable or opposite. And tragedy and comedy aren't binary: there is tragi-comedy, and works that are neither (epic, lyric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a bit unclear what you’re asking. But first, let’s make sure we’re understanding the idiom *two sides of the same coin* in the same way.

The *OED*’s entry for **side** *n.* offers:

> **c.** With reference to a coin.
> **(a)** ***two sides of the same coin*** and variants: two things, processes, etc., which are closely related or interdependent even
> though they seem different; two different aspects of the same
> situation or phenomenon.

Are you asking what the word is for a pair of words relative to the coin metaphor? They would indeed be — as you suggested —  **complements**:

> **5. a.** Something which, when added, completes or makes up a whole; each of two parts which mutually complete each other, or supply each
> other’s deficiencies.

We need both of the words or we don’t have two sides for our “coin.”

Situated metaphorically on either side of our coin, the words are now also **opposites**:

> **B.** *adj.*
> **1. a.** Situated on the other or further side, or on either side, of an intervening line, space, or thing; contrary in position; facing.
> Frequently with *to* and (now less commonly) *from*; formerly also
> with †*against*.

But maybe you are asking for a word that describes the semantic relationship between a particular pair of words?

Well, one might argue that they could all be cast as forms of opposites (if they couldn’t, we probably wouldn’t deploy them in a coin metaphor).

We have gradable antonyms — like *laughter* and *tears* — that sit on either end of a scale. They’re two sides of a human emotion coin.

We have binary antonyms — like *winning* and *losing* — where you have one or the other. They’re two sides of a game coin.

We have relational antonyms — like *teacher* and *student* — where you can’t be called a teacher if you don’t have a student and the other way around. They’re two sides of an education coin.

*Ball* and *strike* can be considered binary antonyms: pitches not hit must be one or the other. They’re two sides of the “not hit” coin. Same for *fair* and *foul* for pitches hit.

*Reading* is an act of intaking; *writing* is an opposite act — that of outputting. They’re two sides of a literacy coin.

And so on.

<sub>Definition sources: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: Ah!  Binary antonyms! Never heard of it and it's right! Binary also called hemispheric antonym...  https://amalayka.wordpress.com/grammar-2/semantic/binary-and-non-binary/

Answer (score 1):

I agree that *complement* works well in many cases. However, if you want to contrast two parts of some whole, or *propose*  that two things can be thought of as complements, perhaps:

**flip side**

> 2. an opposite, reverse, or sharply contrasted side or aspect of
>    something or someone
>    *The flip side of their charitable activities is a desire for publicity.* [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/flip-side)

> The **flip side** of envy is, of course, idealisation. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Post_Jungians_Today/0kfrKGLC8z4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%20of%20envy%22&pg=PA206&printsec=frontcover).
> Greed is the **flip side** of envy. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/State_of_Confusion/BTAB6-SfpIoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%20of%20envy%22&pg=PA84&printsec=frontcover).
> Now the **flip side** of envy is altruism. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rawls_s_A_Theory_of_Justice/GUkSBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%20of%20envy%22&pg=PA83&printsec=frontcover).
> People-pleasing is the **flip side** of envy. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Purpose_Driven_Life/m3XJ3x0cFsYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%20of%20envy%22&pg=PT339&printsec=frontcover).

> Apropos the dialectic of religious consciousness, Aristophanic comedy
> offers another means of contemplating the flight of the Greek gods.
> As such, it is something of the **flip side** of the same phenomenon that
> tragedy reveals... *[Hegel on Tragedy and Comedy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hegel_on_Tragedy_and_Comedy/we4lEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%22%20tragedy&pg=PT177&printsec=frontcover)*

> The **flip side** of the celebration of freedom, though, is the
> challenge of order. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encountering_Tragedy/qZQBU4HahTIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%22%20tragedy&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcover).

> This leads to grave injustice—the **flip side** of democracy—in the
> form of income concentration favoring a few and the deteriorating
> quality of life for the vast majority of citizens. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ultimate_Tragedy/6vfBDo9MR14C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flip%20side%22%20tragedy&pg=PT94&printsec=frontcover).